# mockjax how to test url with parameters

Tags: qunit, mockjax

I am having problem to mock one end point. Mockjax intercept the request when retrieving the params the from the URL. Nevertheless,  when I add them into the URL or the data object, the request passes through.

I need to make two occurrences of this call pass. Otherwise, my integration tests are failing.

I am working with global calls. All other calls are working properly minus this one.

/* catches*/

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '*search-by-keyword',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : tokenId },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    responseText: mockLiferaySearchResponseSuccess
});
```

/* passes through*/

```
$.mockjax(
{ url: '*search-by-keyword',
    data: {
           page: '0',
           perPage: '5',
           lang: 'en',
           path: 'http://testbanner.ypg.com/portal',
           type: 'webcontent',
           keyword: 'yellow'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : tokenId },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    responseText: mockLiferaySearchResponseSuccess
});
```

Comment: Is your `$.ajax()` call using the `data` option or putting things in a query string on the `url` option? They will have to be the same for the mockjax request to capture it.